# Find the Shortest Distance between sets of GPS Coordinates - Python

Tags: python, arrays, gps, coordinates, distance

For example this array of GPS Coordinates:

```
GPSS = [{"Lat":40.641099,"Lon": -73.917094},{"Lat":40.60442,"Lon": -74.054873},{"Lat":40.779582,"Lon": -73.920213},{"Lat":40.651616,"Lon": -73.89097},{"Lat":40.755183,"Lon": -73.846248}]
```

I have already calculated the Distances below for each possible combination:

```
Distances = [{'GPSS': [0, 1], 'Distance': 12.34895151892164}, {'GPSS': [0, 2], 'Distance': 15.380561959360797}, {'GPSS': [0, 3], 'Distance': 2.499303143635897}, {'GPSS': [0, 4], 'Distance': 14.012560598709298}, {'GPSS': [1, 2], 'Distance': 22.53687775052488}, {'GPSS': [1, 3], 'Distance': 14.824576927209662}, {'GPSS': [1, 4], 'Distance': 24.318038568441654}, {'GPSS': [2, 3], 'Distance': 14.423642658224264}, {'GPSS': [2, 4], 'Distance': 6.807346029310139}, {'GPSS': [3, 4], 'Distance': 12.106031672624894}]
```

0,1 = referring to 40.641099,-73.917094 and 40.60442,-74.054873

1,4 = 40.641099,-73.917094 and 40.755183,-73.846248

I would now like to find out the shortest Distance (route) to visit each set of coordinates, so it's most likely not going to be point 0 to 1 to 2 to 3 to 4.
But something like 1 to 3 to 4 to 2 to 0.

**How would I accomplish something like this?**

This is as far as I got:

```
for index, d in enumerate(Distances):
    print(d['GPSS'])
    Total = d['Distance']
    Start = d['GPSS'][1] #[0]
    CheckPoints = []
    CheckPoints.append(d['GPSS'][0])
    CheckPoints.append(d['GPSS'][1])
    for index2, d2 in enumerate(Distances):
        if index != index2:
            if Start == d2['GPSS'][0]: #0-1, 1-2, 2-3
                Total += d2['Distance']
                Start += 1
                if d2['GPSS'][0] not in CheckPoints:
                    CheckPoints.append(d2['GPSS'][0])
                if d2['GPSS'][1] not in CheckPoints:
                    CheckPoints.append(d2['GPSS'][1])
                #print(CheckPoints)
                print("+"+str(d2['Distance'])+" = "+str(Total)+" | "+str(Start)+" - "+str(d2['GPSS']))

    if len(CheckPoints) <= len(GPSS)-1: #GPPS - is from above
        for x in range(len(GPSS)-1):
            if x not in CheckPoints:
                for d3 in Distances:
                    if d3['GPSS'][0] == x and d3['GPSS'][1] == CheckPoints[-1]:
                        print("HERE")
                        print(d3)
                        Total += d3['Distance']
                        break

    print(Total)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Look up dijkstra's algorithm

Comment: @user1558604 Isn't this Traveling Salesman Problem? - op wants to visit each set of coordinates, not only the shortest route

Answer (score 5):

The best way to do what you are looking for is to create a **Graph**. If you do not know what that is, you should look it up as it's a very important data structure. You will probably also need to know what it is to fully understand the following code. Python does not have a built in graph so you need to create your own.

The type of graph you are going to need is a **un-directed weighted graph** with all of the nodes, or in your case GPS coordinates, connected to each other. Then you can sort the graph by using a form of "**Dijkstra's Algorithm**" to find the shortest path to all of the points.

Below is an implementation of what you are looking for. However I coded this to work with a list containing lists of paired coordinates. It also includes a driver, driver(), you can call to test it out.

I wrote this up quick and didn't code it as a class, but in the real world you most definitely should.

As a note, when you run the driver function it will execute the code and print out all of the possible paths and their weights for the provided coordinate list. "Weight" in your case refers to the distance between the points. The list printed shows the path it took with "1" referring to the pair of points at index "0" of the coordinate list. The next number in the list is the pair of points it went to next.

*If you have any further questions feel free to ask*

```
from collections import defaultdict
from math import sqrt

# Shortest path to all coordinates from any node
# Coordinates must be provided as a list containing lists of
# x/y pairs. ie [[23.2321, 58.3123], [x.xxx, y.yyy]]


def distance_between_coords(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    distance = sqrt(((x2 - x1) ** 2) + ((y2 - y1) ** 2))
    return distance


# Adds "names" to coordinates to use as keys for edge detection
def name_coords(coords):
    coord_count = 0
    for coord in coords:
        coord_count += 1
        coord.append(coord_count)
    return coords


# Creates a weighted and undirected graph
# Returns named coordinates and their connected edges as a dictonary
def graph(coords):
    coords = name_coords(coords)
    graph = defaultdict(list)
    edges = {}
    for current in coords:
        for comparer in coords:
            if comparer == current:
                continue
            else:
                weight = distance_between_coords(current[0], current[1],
                                                 comparer[0], comparer[1])
                graph[current[2]].append(comparer[2])
                edges[current[2], comparer[2]] = weight
    return coords, edges


# Returns a path to all nodes with least weight as a list of names
# from a specific node
def shortest_path(node_list, edges, start):
    neighbor = 0
    unvisited = []
    visited = []
    total_weight = 0
    current_node = start
    for node in node_list:
        if node[2] == start:
            visited.append(start)
        else:
            unvisited.append(node[2])
    while unvisited:
        for index, neighbor in enumerate(unvisited):
            if index == 0:
                current_weight = edges[start, neighbor]
                current_node = neighbor
            elif edges[start, neighbor] < current_weight:
                current_weight = edges[start, neighbor]
                current_node = neighbor
        total_weight += current_weight
        unvisited.remove(current_node)
        visited.append(current_node)
    return visited, total_weight


def driver():
    coords = [[1.7592675, 92.4836507], [17.549836, 32.457398],
              [23.465896, 45], [25.195462, 37.462742],
              [42.925274, 63.234028], [2.484631, 5.364871],
              [50.748376, 36.194797]]
    coords, edges = graph(coords)
    shortest_path(coords, edges, 3)
    shortest_path_taken = []
    shortest_path_weight = 0

    for index, node in enumerate(coords):
        path, weight = shortest_path(coords, edges, index + 1)
        print('--------------------------------------')
        print("Path", index + 1, "=", path)
        print("Weight =", weight)
        if index == 0:
            shortest_path_weight = weight
            shortest_path_taken = path
        elif weight < shortest_path_weight:
            shortest_path_weight = weight
            shortest_path_taken = path
    print('--------------------------------------')
    print("The shortest path to all nodes is:", shortest_path_taken)
    print("The weight of the path is:", shortest_path_weight)
```

---

Edit:
Here is what the output will look like when you call the driver function:

```
--------------------------------------
Path 1 = [1, 5, 3, 4, 2, 7, 6]
Weight = 386.3252849770695
--------------------------------------
Path 2 = [2, 4, 3, 6, 7, 5, 1]
Weight = 189.3710721663407
--------------------------------------
Path 3 = [3, 4, 2, 5, 7, 6, 1]
Weight = 173.99235180101968
--------------------------------------
Path 4 = [4, 3, 2, 7, 5, 6, 1]
Weight = 172.86112533927678
--------------------------------------
Path 5 = [5, 3, 7, 4, 2, 1, 6]
Weight = 247.08415835699554
--------------------------------------
Path 6 = [6, 2, 4, 3, 7, 5, 1]
Weight = 330.1567215845902
--------------------------------------
Path 7 = [7, 4, 5, 3, 2, 6, 1]
Weight = 247.70066871941674
--------------------------------------
The shortest path to all nodes is: [4, 3, 2, 7, 5, 6, 1]
The weight of the path is: 172.86112533927678
[Finished in 0.1s]*
```

Comment: Hello. I am not necessarily saying you are wrong, but there are the values I got when I implemented the algorithm. I am not sure which one of us is wrong. Any insight?

--------------------------------------
Path 1 = [1, 5, 3, 4, 2, 6, 7]
Weight = 182.30775878123
--------------------------------------
Path 2 = [2, 4, 3, 5, 7, 6, 1]
Weight = 216.078999832647
--------------------------------------
Path 3 = [3, 4, 2, 6, 7, 5, 1]
Weight = 183.788612031565
--------------------------------------
Path 4 = [4, 3, 2, 6, 7, 5, 1]
Weight = 188.518109747981

Comment: Path 5 = [5, 3, 4, 2, 6, 7, 1]
Weight = 206.429943633481
--------------------------------------
Path 6 = [6, 2, 4, 3, 5, 7, 1]
Weight = 177.307960493246
--------------------------------------
Path 7 = [7, 4, 3, 2, 6, 5, 1]
Weight = 199.283555617923
--------------------------------------
The shortest path to all nodes is: [6, 2, 4, 3, 5, 7, 1]
The weight of the path is: 177.307960493246
--------------------------------------